# Spring Scheduler is running more threads than configured

Tags: java, spring, scheduled-tasks

I have configured spring scheduler via XML to run a thread pool with 4 threads.
But in JVisualVM I see 7 threads running with the choosen name.

```
<task:scheduler id="backendScheduler" pool-size="4"/>
```

The scheduler is used in 3 places:

```
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="backendScheduler">
  <task:scheduled ref="myOtherBean" method="doSomething" fixed-delay="2000"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

It's also strange that there are 7 and not 4*2=8

Anyone have experienced the same? Any idea how to have only 4 threads.

[image]

Comment: `1,2,3,4` is what I see

Comment: yes, but you see 1 twice and 2 and 3 also. Only 4 is once.